# MNIST tensorflow - cant figure out whats wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to figure out why this is not working for hours but I am getting nowhere. Would really appreciate some help.

It's basically a copy of the tutorial found on the tensorflow website with a few tweaks for using a local data set. But I only get 10% accuracy, which is the same as guessing!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
yi = df['label']
df = df.drop('label',1)

labels=[]
for i in range(len(yi)):
    #convert to one hot 
    label = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    label[yi[i]]= 1
    labels.append(label)

labels = np.array(labels)
df = df.as_matrix()

df_train, df_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df,labels)




x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)



sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

def next_batch(num, data, labels):

    #get batches for training 

    idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]

    return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)

for _ in range(1000):
    df_train0, y_train0 = next_batch(100, df_train, y_train)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={ x: df_train0, y_: y_train0})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:df_test, y_:y_test}))
```

Comment: You're not using any hidden layers? Is this just a linear model? What accuracy do you expect?

Comment: I expected at least 90. I know that there are many more layers I could add, but need to get this working first!

Comment: Without having access to your training data, it's no possible to run this and try to debug. Could you upload the data file you're running this with?

Comment: I got it form https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are initializing W with 0s, therefore there is no gradient to modify and all the logits will be 0s

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
```

You should initialize it randomly in order to break the symmetry.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 10]))
```

**Edit:** It isn't necessary to randomize as the target logit will break the symmetry. Nevertheless, if there were a hidden layer, it would be necessary. The real problem seems to be in the scale of the input. Dividing by 255 should solve the problem.

Comment: I think that the gradient is the gradient of the entropy equation not the regression. Either way it doesn't help.

Comment: The gradient is backpropagated to the W variable. You also need to scale down and center your inputs, dividing by 255, for example.

Comment: @ManoloSantos If initializing the weights with zeros is the problem, why does the official [MNIST for ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) tutorial state "Since we are going to learn W and b, it doesn't matter very much what they initially are."?

Comment: @Jarad, you are right. Initially I thought there was a hidden layer. In that case, you would need to break the symmetry by randomly initializing the weights. The real problem is the scale of the inputs, divide them by 255 and it will work. I already updated my answer.

Comment: why cant it deal with unscaled inputs?

Comment: @ElkanaTheGreat It is a very good question. In this case, I would say that with such big values, you are saturating the output non-linearity, therefore the gradient becomes close to 0 and it can't learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this helps improve accuracy so if anyone can give a better answer, please do!

I changed:

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

to be:

```
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
```

Full Code Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.stats import entropy

def next_batch(num, data, labels):
  '''get batches for training'''

  idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
  np.random.shuffle(idx)
  idx = idx[:num]
  data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
  labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]

  return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df_X = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df_y = df['label']

y_one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(df_y.values.reshape(-1, 1))

df_train, df_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_X.values, y_one_hot)

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for _ in range(1000):
  df_train0, y_train0 = next_batch(100, df_train, y_train)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={ x: df_train0, y_: y_train0})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:df_test, y_:y_test}))
```

Resulting accuracy: around `0.88`

Comment: The problem with the original version is that `tf.log(big_number)` is `inf`. Therefore, it is inestable. The second version prevents this, scaling down the logits to avoid this instability.

Comment: **Correction**: Actually, in order to prevent the instability, the second version uses the identity `log(e^x) == x`.